# How can you tell dotnet ef database update command where migration files are located

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a project on Mac. The solution has multiple projects with in it, `Domain`, `WebPortal` and `API`.

From within the `WebPortal` project I've created a migration by running the following command from within that project;

```
dotnet ef migrations add ApplicationUser_Deactivate -o ../SolutionName.Domain/data/migrations
```

This has created the migration files within the `Domain` project.

The problem is, running the command `dotnet ef database update` doesn't appear to pickup the migration files from that location and I can't seem to find a way to tell the command where the migration files are.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

`dotnet ef database update --project .SolutionName.Domain/data/migrations` or

`dotnet ef database update --p SolutionName.Domain`

Argument `p`, `project` - Relative path to the project folder of the target project. Default value is the current folder.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, I see an error 'No project was found in Directory ../MyProject/Sql/Migrations'